# Replace figure with item change and overlap images inside item change

Tags: beamer

I need to replace figures with item change I found way how to do that. But I also need to overlap images inside item. It means images should overlap within the item. And with the change of the item, a new group of images should be shown that will overlap each other. I am confused how to do that, because I tried code inserted but it does not work on that way.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 10pt]{beamer}
\def\Put(#1,#2)#3{\leavevmode\makebox(0,0){\put(#1,#2){#3}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{CFD}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item <1-> aaa
    \item <2-> bbb
    \item <3-> ccc
    \item <4-> ddd
  \end{itemize}

\includegraphics<1>[height=3cm]{air.png}\pause
\Put(10,50){\color{blue}\includegraphics<1>[height=3cm]{air1.jpg}}\pause
\Put(100,30){\color{red}\includegraphics<1>[height=3cm]{cabin2.png}}

\includegraphics<2>[height=3cm]{water.png}\pause

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a bit overkill, but you could use tikz:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

% trick taken from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1989
\tikzset{
    use page relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current page.south west)},
        x={(current page.south east)},
        y={(current page.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{CFD}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item <1-> aaa
    \item <4-> bbb
    \item <6-> ccc
    \item <7-> ddd
  \end{itemize}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,use page relative coordinates]
    \node<1-3> at (0.7,0.7) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}};
    \node<2-3> at (0.8,0.8) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}};
    \node<3> at (0.75,0.6) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}};    
    \node<4-5> at (0.75,0.45) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}};     
    \node<5> at (0.7,0.5) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}};          
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You did not understand, I have multiple images inside one item, multiple images inside <1>, they need to overlap each other.  After that I need to change it for other group of images inside next item.

Comment: @nick_name Maybe you could include a sketch of your desired result in your question?

Comment: @nick_name Thanks for your edit. I still think tikz is an easy solution.